# Weird behavior of reduce method in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Anyone can explain me this situation?

In the second call the function, the result is `{cat: 2, cat,cat: 1, dog: 1, frog: 1}`.

However, I thought that the result was going to be `{cat: 4, dog: 1, frog: 1}`.

What's going on here?

```js
var animals = ['cat', 'cat', ['cat'], 'dog', 'frog'];

var otherAnimals = ['cat', 'cat', ['cat', 'cat'], 'dog', 'frog'];

function reducingArrays(arraySource) {
  var countedData = arraySource.reduce(function(allItems, item) {
    if (item in allItems) {
      allItems[item]++;
    } else {
      allItems[item] = 1;
    }
    return allItems;
  }, {});

  console.log(countedData);
}

reducingArrays(animals); // {cat: 3, dog: 1, frog: 1}

reducingArrays(otherAnimals); // {cat: 2, cat,cat: 1, dog: 1, frog: 1}
// What I expected: {cat: 4, dog: 1, frog: 1}
```

Comment: `['cat']` is cast to `'cat'`. `['cat','cat']` is cast to `'cat,cat'`. You're using arrays as object keys, which converts them to strings. You want some kind of recursive function.

Comment: Alternatively use [`[].concat(...arr)` to flatten an array](https://jsfiddle.net/nqc1n5h3/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert single element to array:

```js
var animals = ['cat', 'cat', ['cat'], 'dog', 'frog'];

var otherAnimals = ['cat', 'cat', ['cat', 'cat'], 'dog', 'frog'];

function reducingArrays(arraySource) {
  var countedData = arraySource.reduce(function(allItems, item) {
    var arr = Array.isArray(item) ? item : [item];
    allItems[arr[0]] = (allItems[arr[0]] || 0) + arr.length;
    return allItems;
  }, {});

  console.log(countedData);
}

reducingArrays(animals);

reducingArrays(otherAnimals);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to handle if one of the objects is an array:

```
function reducingArrays(arraySource){
    var countedData = arraySource.reduce(function (allItems, item) {
        var items = [item];
        if(item.constructor === Array){
            items = item;
        }
        items.forEach(function(item){
            if (item in allItems) {
                allItems[item]++;
            } else {
                allItems[item] = 1;
            }               
        });
        return allItems;
    }, {});
    console.log(countedData);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yoh could use a check for array and use the same callback of `reduce` for nested arrays.

```js
function reducingArrays(arraySource) {
    return arraySource.reduce(function iter(allItems, item) {
        if (Array.isArray(item)) {
            return item.reduce(iter, allItems);
        }
        allItems[item] = (allItems[item] || 0) +1;
        return allItems;
    }, {});
}


var animals = ['cat', 'cat', ['cat'], 'dog', 'frog'];
var otherAnimals = ['cat', 'cat', ['cat', 'cat'], 'dog', 'frog'];

console.log(reducingArrays(animals));      // { cat: 3, dog: 1, frog: 1}
console.log(reducingArrays(otherAnimals)); // { cat: 4, dog: 1, frog: 1 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The first comment already explained, that this has to do with how Arrays are stringified since Object keys can only be strings.

Here a way how you can handle nested Arrays in your function.

```js
function countAnimals(source) {
  function _count(allItems, item) {
    if (Array.isArray(item)) {
      return item.reduce(_count, acc);
    }

    if (item in allItems) {
      allItems[item]++;
    } else {
      allItems[item] = 1;
    }
    return acc;
  }

  //needs `source` to be an Array
  return source.reduce(_count, {});

  //this would also work, if `source` is a single animal.
  //like countAnimals('dog');
  //I prefer this approach because it is more flexible 
  //on what the function can deal with, 
  //and it doesn't cost me even a single extra line of code
  //return _count({}, source);
}


var animals = ['cat', 'cat', ['cat'], 'dog', 'frog'];
console.log("simple", countAnimals(animals));

var otherAnimals = ['cat', 'cat', ['cat', 'cat'], 'dog', 'frog'];
console.log("nested", countAnimals(otherAnimals));

//and a deeply nested structure
var moreAnimals = ['mouse', ['cat', ['dog', 'duck', ['frog']], 'cat'], 'dog', 'frog'];
console.log("multiple levels", countAnimals(moreAnimals));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{top: 0;max-height: 100%!important}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your array is only going to be nested one level deep you can use `[].concat(...arr)` to flatten it before you iterate over it with `reduce`.

In this example I've also made the condition a little more concise.

```js
var animals = ['cat', 'cat', ['cat'], 'dog', 'frog'];
var otherAnimals = ['cat', 'cat', ['cat', 'cat'], 'dog', 'frog'];

function reducingArrays(arraySource) {
  return [].concat(...arraySource).reduce(function(allItems, item) {
    allItems[item] = allItems[item] || 0;
    allItems[item]++;
    return allItems;
  }, {});
}

const result = reducingArrays(animals);
const result2 = reducingArrays(otherAnimals);

console.log(result);
console.log(result2);
```